# Fourier transform in space

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have an expression on the form
$$
g_i(x+r\delta t, t+\delta t) = T_{ij}g_j(x,t)
$$
and I would like for find its Fourier transform. According to my book it should be
$$
g_i(k,t+\delta t) = \Gamma_{ij}g_j(k,t)
$$
where
$$
\Gamma_{ij}=diag(\exp(-ik\cdot r\delta t))T_{ij}
$$
Can anyone explain how this FT is done? I have no idea how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand the expression "diag". I obtain$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\int dx\exp [ikx]g_{i}(x+r\delta t,t+\delta t) &=&\exp [-ikr\delta t]\int
dy\exp [iky]g_{i}(y,t+\delta t) \\
&=&\exp [-ikr\delta t]\tilde{g}_{i}(k,\delta t)=T_{ij}\int dx\exp
[ikx]g_{j}(x,t)\\=T_{ij}\tilde{g}_{j}(k,t)
\end{eqnarray*}$$so $$\tilde{g}_{i}(k,\delta t)=\exp [ikr\delta t]T_{ij}\tilde{g}_{j}(k,t)
$$
There is a difference in the sign of the exponential. What is your definition of the Fourier transform?